# Target a specfic control in a ASP:DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to find a way to make a `asp:RegularExpressionValidor` target a specific control when it is inside a `asp:DataList`

The `asp:DataList` is in the following code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlUserInputs" runat="server" DataKeyField="tagname" ItemStyle-CssClass="paddingBottom20" CssClass="layout">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <npo:UserInput ID="ctrlUserInput" runat="server" /> // user control 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

the `npo:UserInput` contains the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="UserInput.ascx.vb" Inherits="web_controls_publication_UserInput" %>

    ...
            <asp:Label ID="lblUserInput" runat="server" Visible="false" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserInput" runat="server" Visible="false" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Width="100%"/>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator" runat="server"
             ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:PageText, LETTER_GOODSANDSERVICESXML_WRONGFORMAT %>" ValidationExpression="^[Cc]lass\s[0-9]{1,2}:\s{1}[^\n]*(?:\r?\n[Cc]lass\s[0-9]{1,2}:\s{1}[^\n]*)*$"
            ControlToValidate="txtUserInput"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>    
    ...
```

My problem is the `RegularExpressionValidor` validates the control `txtUserInput` but if my dataList calls,let's say, 3 times this code, the validator will apply on the 3 `txtUserInput` occurences. I want it to apply **only to the first**

Thank you in advance for your advices

Comment: You are going to have write a custom validator -- you might be able to leverage the regularexpressionvalidator

Comment: That's the only solution ? i mean there is nothing else than doing a server-side validation function ?

Comment: You can create a property named `Index` and then bind the ItemIndex in your `ItemTemplate` to your `UserInput` user control's index property, then in your UserInput template surround the regularexpression validator with an `If` condition that checks if `Index == 0`

Comment: @BYU not sure what you mean -- a custom validator can do client side validation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done. First add a property to `UserInput.ascx` code behind. In this case `Validate`

```
public partial class UserInput : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public bool Validate { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
    }
}
```

Then bind the new variable to the `Visible` property of the `RegularExpressionValidator`

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator" Visible='<%# Validate %>'
```

Then to enable the first item in the `DataList`, set the new `Visible` property in the aspx containing the UserControl.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlUserInputs" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <npo:UserInput ID="ctrlUserInput" Validate='<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**VB** - using https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/

```
Public Partial Class UserInput
    Inherits Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Property Validate As Boolean

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class
```